# How to scrape the invisible dynamic elements without selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, python-requests

I am working on a simulated login on [nike.com](https://www.nike.com/login). The login content is dynamic, which means it was set invisible in the source codes:

```
<div class="mex-unite-container hidden">

  <div id="nike-unite-login-view" class="nike-unite" style="display:none"></div>

</div>
```

After analyzing the source code, I found the following javascript source code may be related to the issue:

```
  if (mexUniteContainer && mexUniteContainer.classList.contains('hidden')) {
      mexUniteContainer.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
```

The `display:none` codes will not be viewed before the execution of the javascript codes. How to access the codes without using selenium? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: can you share your url if it is public?

Comment: @KunduK nike.com

Comment: Which browser are you trying? i can't see any popup either chrome or Firefox?can you post snapshot of your modal popup?

Comment: @KunduK click join/login in nike on the right top corner. the login form is a pop up you cannot view in source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SplashJS works for me. 
Splash is a javascript rendering service. It’s a lightweight web browser with an HTTP API, implemented in Python 3 using Twisted and QT5. The (twisted) QT reactor is used to make the service fully asynchronous allowing to take advantage of webkit concurrency via QT main loop. Some of Splash features:

- process multiple webpages in parallel;
- get HTML results and/or take screenshots;
- turn OFF images or use Adblock Plus rules to make rendering faster;
- execute custom JavaScript in page context;
- write Lua browsing scripts;
- develop Splash Lua scripts in Splash-Jupyter Notebooks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `WebdriverWait` and following xpath to access the login form.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.nike.com/')
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//div[@id="AccountNavigationContainer"]//button//span[contains(.,"Join / Log In To Nike⁠Plus Account")]'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//input[@placeholder="Email"]'))).send_keys('pajarnas')
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//input[@placeholder="Password"]'))).send_keys('pajarnas')
```

---

[image]

Comment: @pajarnas Specifying what _to_ use would be more helpful.

Comment: @jhpratt requests?

Comment: @pajarnas That just gets you the page, it doesn't parse anything.

Comment: I updated my question, I hope it will be more clear!

Comment: I think Splash helped me to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe webbot?  webbot even works web pages which have dynamically changing id and classnames and has more methods and features than selenium or mechanize.

Here's a snippet :)

```
from webbot import Browser 
web = Browser()
web.go_to('google.com') 
web.click('Sign in')
web.type('mymail@gmail.com' , into='Email')
web.click('NEXT' , tag='span')
web.type('mypassword' , into='Password' , id='passwordFieldId') # specific selection
web.click('NEXT' , tag='span') # you are logged in ^_^
```

Or, keep it super-simple.

```
import requests
url = 'http://example.com/userinfo.php'
values = {'username': 'user',
          'password': 'pass'}

r = requests.post(url, data=values)
print r.content
```

Comment: I tried but it still works with selenium! I updated my question, I hope it will be more clear!

Comment: I think Splash helped me to figure it out.